# C++: Read from stdin as data is written into pipe

Tags: c++, bash, piping

I have two C++ programs: one that prints a message to stdout, and the other that listens to stdin and prints all content from the stream. They are named `out` and `in` respectively.

**out.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout<<"HELLO";
        usleep(1000000);
        cout<<"HELLO";
}
```

**in.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        string input;
        while(cin>>input) {
                cout<<input;
        }
}
```

As it currently stands, piping the data from `out` to `in` waits for two seconds, then prints `HELLOHELLO`:

```
~$ ./out | ./in

#...two seconds later:
~$ ./out | ./in
HELLOHELLO~$
```

I'm sure this is a simple question, but is it possible for `in` to print each `HELLO` as `out` prints it? I've read that [piped commands run concurrently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run), but I must be misunderstanding this concept for this particular situation. The desired performance is:

```
~$ ./out | ./in

#...one second later:
~$ ./out | ./in
HELLO

#...one second after that:
~$ ./out | ./in
HELLOHELLO~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues going on here.

The first is output buffering. You need to [flush the output stream](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/94227). 
Probably easiest way is `cout.flush()`.

The second is string reading reads whole words, and you're only outputting one, with a pause between.

You either need to switch to character based input, or put a separator between the words.

Character based input would look like this

```
int main() {
        char input;
        while(cin>>input) {
                cout<<input;
        }
}
```

Adding a separator would look like this:

```
int main() {
        cout<<"HELLO";
        cout<<" ";
        usleep(1000000);
        cout<<"HELLO";
}
```

Note the additional space.