# Monitoring data in named pipe (FIFO) in C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I want to chain the stdin and stdout of several programs via named pipe. These programs act like services or daemons so I wish they could keep reading from a FIFO until they are blocked due to the FIFO is cleared. I modified the code from the answer in the question [C++: Read from stdin as data is written into pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29689027/10627291) as below to verify my idea:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {            
    char input;
    while(1){
        while(std::cin>>input){                 
            std::cout<<input;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I compiled this to an executable named `t`. Now open a terminal and enter these commands:

```
mkfifo ff
./t > ff
```

And open a new terminal and enter this:

```
./t < ff
```

Now inputs to the first terminal will appear at the second terminal, and the `t` in the second terminal would be blocked as soon as it has read all characters in the FIFO. Everything is fine by now, but when I terminate the `t` in the first terminal, the `t` in the second terminal is not blocked anymore, nevertheless the FIFO is cleared already, and soon takes up 100% CPU usage even when the FIFO is deleted.

My questions:

- Why the second `t` is not blocked when the first `t` exits in my case;
- Is there anyway to keep the second `t` being blocked when the first `t` exits;
- Maybe my whole idea about chaining programs via FIFO is wrong. Is there a better practise to connect the stdin and stdout of several programs in shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the second t is not blocked when the first t exits in my case

When the first `t` is terminated, it generates an end of file on the fifo and the second `t` is not blocked anymore.

> Is there anyway to keep the second t being blocked when the first t
> exits

This is a problem in inter process communication (IPC). The input/output to the IPC mechanism (fifo, here) should be done inside the C++ program.

> Is there a better practise to connect the stdin and stdout of several
> programs in shell?

If the processes are related you can connect by the pipe (|) operator. Otherwise, using a fifo with redirection appears to be the only way.